# ArcGIS Server 10.1 can't add directory

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, cache

I add new SAN Disk to windows server for build cache.
but ArcGIS Server can't add directory.

drive C = local disk
drive D = SAN disk

I login with ArcGIS Server Account , I can create directory in drive D.

[image]

How to solve this problem.

Comment: What format is SANdisk in? NTFS (New Technology File System) is the recommend format

Comment: You may need to bounce the ArcGIS Server service; Windows might not reread the volume list while the application is running.

Comment: @Mapperz SAN disk is NTFS.

Comment: @Vince I restart ArcGIS Server service many time. but it same.